# Why is training so slow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I started to train a model with my GeForce RTX 2070 with 16 GB RAM, but it takes a lot of time even for one epoch. For example, 1 epoch takes more than 10 hours. As it will require near 100 epochs for a good result. So I've met problems with training process, as I don't have time to wait a month to finish training.

The dataset is near 500000 images with total size 200 GB.

I am using YOLO (in darknet) with weights tiny-yolov2. My tensorflow version is 1.12.0. Weights and configuration files were downloaded from official site. GPU usage in options is set as 0.8.

Before starting training my GPU usage is:

[image]

After starting training:

[image]

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from darkflow_master2.darkflow.net.build import TFNet
import cv2
import os
import tensorflow as tf
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

options = {"model": "cfg/yolov2-3c.cfg",
           "load": "bin/yolov2.weights",
           "batch": 64,
           "epoch": 2,
           "gpu": 0.8,
           "train": True,
           "savepb": True,
           "save": 1000,
           "annotation": "./annotations/",
           "dataset": "./images/",
           "lr  ": 1e-3}

tfnet = TFNet(options)
```

Comment: @moderators: the darknet tag seems to have a double meaning. The ML toolkit and the overlay network. What can be done about this ?

Comment: @Jeffrey in my case I am using Darknet neural network framework.

Comment: As it stands, the tag refers to something else so it doesn't belong on this question. Also, it's impossible to help you without seeing some code (_minimal_ example). GPU usage is very low so there is likely some inefficiencies/bottlenecks in your code.

Comment: @xdurch0 provided with part of code. Also GPU usage with 0.8 is enough because after usage 1.0 PC can hangs up.

Comment: What I mean is that the screenshot shows a GPU usage of 12% which means its compute capacity is not used properly. There might be a bottleneck e.g. with data loading/preprocessing. Hard to say because the code still doesn't show much (although I have to admit I'm not familiar with darknet).

Comment: @IKKLX have you fixed this?